# 504 Error on Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm running a Ruby on Rails app with Nginx and my app is returning a `504 Gateway Time-out` when I visit it on the web.  I was wondering what causes this and how do I fix it?

If I restart the server will that fix it?  Once a 504 occurs will the app keep returning this error to all subsequent visitors once it's triggered once?

I didn't change the code or receive any large influx of new users, but apparently the app has been giving this error for at least the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

A 504 from nginx means that nginx can not communicate with the Rails upstream backend.

Look at the nginx error logs. Also look in the Rails logs.

Are you using Passenger or proxying to your Rails backend (unicorn, thin, etc)?

Comment: Thanks!  I looked in error.log.1 for Nginx and saw: `014/01/21 18:06:02 [error] 698#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.227.169.220, server: _, request: "$`.  When I tried to look in production.log, the server returned "Killed".  I'm using Unicorn and tried to restart it, but for it said it couldn't restart Master.